# Console::Write выдаёт ошибку неверного формата строки

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Есть такой код и он вываливается с ошибкой что строка имела неверный формат, в чём тут загвоздка,

```
  Console::Write("{\"ChangeType\":\"{0}\", ", e->ChangeType);
```

если разбить на две Console::Write то такой ошибки нет

```
Console::Write("{\"ChangeType\":");
Console::Write("\"{0}\", ", e->ChangeType);
```

Собственно в плюсах не разбираюсь, нужно просто доработать пример чтобы он выводил в консоль JSON который я уже буду обрабатывать.
в принципе мне может помочь ответ на два вопроса,

1. завершает ли строку *Console::Write* ? или только *Console::WriteLine*.
2. можно ли как то сохранить *e->ChangeType* в string

ps: ***e*** это
**static void OnRenamed(Object^ , RenamedEventArgs^ e)**
Сам код почти полная копия FileSystemWatcher с MSDN, но мне нужно чтобы в консоль выводился JSON который я буду забирать из Node.js

Comment: что такое `e` ?

Comment: добавил в текст вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли экранировать фигурную скобочку, из-за этого она считалась как начало форматного плейсхолдера. Правильный код будет выглядеть так:

```
Console::Write("{{\"ChangeType\":\"{0}\", ", e->ChangeType);
```

Для того, чтобы преобразовать значение перечисления в строку *явно*, нужно вызвать для него метод `ToString()`:

```
e->ChangeType.ToString()
```

И нет, метод `Console::Write` не завершает строку, для этого можно и нужно использовать `Console::WriteLine`.

Comment: e->ChangeType.ToString(); не работает, пишет ошибку С2228

Comment: @vnn198 `e->ChangeType.ToString()` вернет вам управляемый тип `String^`. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и приведите код, в котором указанное мной преобразование не работает.

Comment: я делал так -  String^ MyStr = e->ChangeType.ToString(); я пока только более-менее NodeJS освоил, но чую что и Си скоро надо будет заняться.

Comment: @Nikita: Возможно, `ChangeType` — ссылочный тип, и нужно `e->ChangeType->ToString()`.

Comment: @VladD спасибо! @vnn198 , проверьте пожалуйста работает ли у вас вариант Влада. К слову, в моём компиляторе использование стрелочного оператора вместо точки в этой конструкции вызывает ошибку [C2232](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2232):`System::Enum::ToString': left operand has 'enum' type, use '.'`

Comment: Попробовал ещё раз, сейчас ошибок нет, для e->ChangeType нужно через точку, для других параметров через ->